# Flash drive is not visible when inserted

Tags: mount, usb-drive

[image]

My USB flash drive is not visible when it is inserted in Ubuntu 18.04. It's not even visible in Disks.

[image: Disk]

```
$ lsblk 
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop1    7:1    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop2    7:2    0 188.8M  1 loop /snap/vlc/158
loop3    7:3    0   198M  1 loop /snap/vlc/365
loop4    7:4    0 180.5M  1 loop /snap/vlc/190
loop5    7:5    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4830
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Laptop:

- Dell Inspiron N5010
- Ubuntu:18.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of lsusb to your post (with pluged usb stick).

Comment: What is Output of Isusb and also just to add even the command ls /d* | grep sd doesn't show the pen drive.

Comment: Add the output of `lsusb` to your post (with plugged in usb stick). Open terminal and enter this command.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 008: ID 03f0:5a07 Hewlett-Packard identifies my usb stick but how do I use that?

Comment: Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Comment: Connect that pendrive, do to terminal and execute lsblk , do you see the pendrive ? please paste that output

Comment: No I don't see my pendrive when I execute lsblk. Below is the output:              NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop1    7:1    0   198M  1 loop /snap/vlc/365
loop2    7:2    0 188.8M  1 loop /snap/vlc/158
loop3    7:3    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4830
loop4    7:4    0    87M  1 loop /snap/core/5145
loop5    7:5    0 180.5M  1 loop /snap/vlc/190
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

Comment: Hi abu_bua, any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Is there no solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue of not seeing usb drive on disks and `lsblk`, but can be seen in `lsusb`.

And next day I reboot my machine, I saw my usb drive on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't know the reasons causing this. Hope someone who knows this can explain it, which will be appreciated.

So maybe try reboot to see if it works.